# MySQL PID file missing

Tags: mysql, mysql5

Some time ago MySQL stopped working on my server and I've only just got round to looking into it.

When I try and start it with

`service mysqld start`

I get

`Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]mysqld/mysqld.pid).`

If I run

`service mysqld restart`

I get

`MySQL server PID file could not be found!`

My my.cnf file has the following:

`pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

`/var/run/mysqld` is empty, so I run

`touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

and

`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

then try `service mysqld restart` again, and I get `The server quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]mysqld/mysqld.pid)` again, and `/var/run/mysqld` is empty again.

So, I don't really know what to do next. I've read about 20 SO/SF answers and tried what they suggest too and I'm going round in circles. I have MySQL 5.5 installed via Custombuild through Directadmin.

Comment: Verify `/var/run/mysqld` has the correct permissions.  Then check the log files for MySQL to see what else is going on.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, what I had to run was:

```
chmod 0777 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
chmod 0777 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql
```

Then `service mysqld start` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check for permissions on mysql folder. PID should automatically get created when you start the mysql service. What does the mysql error log say ?