# MySQL 8 on CentOS 7 - after update to 8.0.16-1, service won't start

Tags: mysql, centos7

This morning, I updated MySQL as there was an update available, but since then, the service won't start.

Below is a screen grab from the output from systemctl status mysqld.service - the error seems to be "no such file or directory", but I can see the data...

[image: The output from systemctl status mysqld.service]

From mysqld.log

```
2019-04-29T07:52:12.107195Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mo$
2019-04-29T07:52:12.110473Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 7100
2019-04-29T07:52:12.113297Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please$
2019-04-29T07:52:12.113317Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate $
2019-04-29T07:52:19.927908Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80015' to '80016' started.
2019-04-29T07:52:31.456525Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80015' to '80016' completed.
2019-04-29T07:52:45.173350Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-04-29T07:52:45.195659Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2019-04-29T07:52:45.195686Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
2019-04-29T07:52:45.196385Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-04-29T07:52:47.560115Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-04-29T07:55:48.983870Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mo$
2019-04-29T07:55:48.986909Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 3667
2019-04-29T07:55:49.229362Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please$
2019-04-29T07:55:49.229394Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate $
2019-04-29T07:58:43.922205Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mo$
2019-04-29T07:58:43.924734Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 4362
2019-04-29T07:58:43.927787Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please$
2019-04-29T07:58:43.927807Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate $
2019-04-29T07:58:45.734055Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-04-29T07:58:45.739086Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2019-04-29T07:58:45.739110Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
2019-04-29T07:58:45.739676Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-04-29T07:58:47.828539Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-04-29T08:21:45.104646Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mo$
2019-04-29T08:21:45.108410Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 4826
2019-04-29T08:21:45.111420Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please$
2019-04-29T08:21:45.111440Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate $
2019-04-29T08:21:49.874453Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-04-29T08:21:49.891328Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2019-04-29T08:21:49.891353Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
2019-04-29T08:21:49.892014Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-04-29T08:21:52.722060Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I've tried un-installing the update (but found a line in the mysqld.log that says 'downgrade not avialable'.
I've tried deleting ib_logfile0 & ib_logfile1 as suggested in another forum.

Please help...

EDIT:

I've tried the solution from [MySQL PID file missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/634780/mysql-pid-file-missing) (as I couldn't see a pid file), so did:

```
chmod 0777 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
chmod 0777 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql
```

The error has changed - below is the updated output from systemctl status mysqld.service

```
[root@360loa5 mysql]# systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-04-29 09:21:52 BST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 4826 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4807 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4826 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
    Error: 98 (Address already in use)

Apr 29 09:21:44 360loa5.360ss.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Apr 29 09:21:52 360loa5.360ss.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 29 09:21:52 360loa5.360ss.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Apr 29 09:21:52 360loa5.360ss.com systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Apr 29 09:21:52 360loa5.360ss.com systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

In the output from

```
sudo netstat -lntup
```

there isn't anything listed for port 3306...

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Use copy/paste and the formatting tools. Screenshots are useless

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the fix was just to:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak
```

Comment: You had it there in the log - cannot bind the sock file ;-). Good to have ti solved. Please set you answer as accepted ;).

2019-04-29T08:21:49.891328Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2019-04-29T08:21:49.891353Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
2019-04-29T08:21:49.892014Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

Answer (score 0):

This is the common issue, you can alter your MySQL startup script to print if "pid file" exists or not and clean it before starting MySQL. when ever you see an error like below it  means port/resources are already used.

```
Error: 98 (Address already in use)
```